# Shopify liquid javascript parsing

Tags: javascript, interpolation, shopify, liquid

I'm new to Shopify and i'm trying to wrap my head around the following. I know that the liquid templating engine parses the javascript on the Shopify servers.

Is there a way to prevent this? For instance i have a variable to configure my interpolation delimiter like so :

```
    var delimiters = ['{{', '}}']
```

After it gets parsed it looks like this:

```
    var delimiters = ['', '']
```

My javscript doesn't like this. I have a workaround to change the delimiter into something the parsing engine ignores but i was wondering if i could prevent the parsing completely (for my javascript files).

If anyone knows i would appreciate any information.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can use liquid in a javascript file too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer miglio but what if i don't want that? Is there an option to disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to parse something, enclose it within {% raw %} {% endraw %} tags.

Comment: Thank you for this answer Siam Ji. In my specific case the config file of the library i'm using contained brackets and Shopify's liquid parses these symbols. I needed to put {% raw %} and {% endraw %} around my config file to prevent the parsing of config variables.